# No password asked at login screen just start session button with LightDM

Tags: login, password, lightdm

When I first installed Ubuntu I choose NOT to ask me for a password at login. That was ok for that moment cause it didn't ask me any password at login. But now I want to be asked for a login password. I changed the settings to Not start automatically but it doesn't work. My Ubuntu doesn't ask me password at login. What should I do now?

In the automatic login box (in the user accounts setting window) I have it checked to off (0 or Off), the thing is that my LightDM login screen gives me only a "Start Session" button below my user name, instead of the usual password field.

Comment: Can you try checking the box as that answer recommends?

Comment: In the automatic login box (in the user accounts setting window) i have it checked to off (0 or Off), the thing is that my LightDM login screen gives me only a "Start Session" button below my user name, instead of the usual password field.

Comment: no updates yet??

Comment: I've got a similar problem. I got a computer with Ubuntu which I hadn't ever used before. Initially, I disabled the function of using password upon log-in, but then changed my mind and set a password in Terminal. The result is that when logging in, I'm never asked for password. I spent hours searching in forums for help and found that lots of people had issues with passwords. Automatic login option in System Settings is Off. I've established and disabled various keyrings, but nothing changes. I used the command "sudo gpasswd -d username nopasswdlogin". No change. As an ultimate irony, when the

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to user sisco311 from ubuntuforums.org for [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11566335).

I didn't try it but the link posted above shows a command line:

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```

that should work. I did it using the GUI.

The thing is that my user was in the `nopasswdlogin` group.
I had to install the gnome-system-tools which has the GUI to manage users and groups.
Then I ran the users-groups manager and change my user to NOT be part of the `nopasswdlogin` group. Problem Solved. I do have a remaining question: why or how did my user got into that group?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info. Had a heck of a time finding this for some reason.

For those gui users who don't know, find the terminal program in your program list (or for unity-like search for term). You can then use the above command without extra tools.

I also did try searching for the reference of lightdm.conf (like the next post), but in my setup I didn't have that file (my sons pc is setup with edubuntu).

Answer (score 4):

On distributions that use lightdm (xubuntu, ubuntu-studio, ...) you can simply edit

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

If you want user "blah" to auto-login, add the line:

```
autologin-user=blah
```

If you want to be prompted for a password when the system boots, just remove that line, or comment it out (ie. place a # sign at the beginning).

Comment: This helped me. Removing user from nopasswdlogin did not help.

Answer (score 2):

To add a user to nopasswdlogin group:
`sudo gpasswd -a $USER nopasswdlogin`

To remove a user from it:
`sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin`