# 12.10 Login Screen Skipped, Just begins session

Tags: password, login-screen, auto-login

so ive got windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 dual booted with Windows 8 bootloader and grub timeout set to 0.

When it boots i dont even see the orange logo with the orange dots (loading screen) just a blank scrren think a flicker of a purple one, but then i see my fully logged in unity session, i have a password set, i did set it to prompt for login during the instalation and if i go into my user accounts the automatic login is off??

Ive seen this :http://askubuntu.com/questions/100010/no-password-asked-at-login-screen-just-start-session-button-with-lightdm/245432#245432
but i have no clue how to get gnome system tools, if someone has the ppa please share :)

Hoping for it to show me the login screen every time i boot, and ask for password, note i can access the login screen by locking the Pc.

Answer (score 1):

seem to have fixed it by constantly typing

```
sudo gpasswd -d username nopasswdlogin
```

although it never reprted a sucess the problem is fixed:D