# LightDM does not ask for login password

Tags: login, password, sudo, lightdm

I have an auto-logged in non-sudo user called "screen".
I have a passwordless sudo but login-protected user called "support".

I'm pretty sure this was working fine before, somehow maybe the latest dist upgrade broke something...

If I kill X with `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`, I get back to the login screen asking for an username, from there, I can login to the support account that should be protected **without password!** If I logout using the menu, I then get properly asked for a password. But somehow the first login is not protected correctly anymore.

### Tried:

- I tried the answer from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100010/no-password-asked-at-login-screen-just-start-session-button-with-lightdm) but `sudo gpasswd -d support nopasswdlogin` but I get `user 'support' is not a member of 'nopasswdlogin'`
- Tried to remove the passwordless sudo `%sudo    ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` but it did not work either.

### Config:

- my lightdm.conf:

`[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
autologin-user=screen
autologin-user-timeout=0
pam-service=lightdm-autologin
greeter-hide-users=true
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms`

Answer (score 2):

see if your user is in the "nopasswdlogin" group when logged into that user and typing

```
groups
```

into the terminal.

if so remove the group with

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```