# Ubuntu 16.04 boots without asking to log in

Tags: 16.04, boot, login

Recently my Ubuntu 16.04 starts to boot each time without asking me to log in. I would like to enforce entering password before starting every session, how to do this?

**Edit**: In the `System settings` -> `User Accounts` there is no way to (un)set auto-login:
[image]

**Edit2**: I apparently do not belong to user group `nopasswdlogin`. I checked it typing `groups` into console, the result is: `adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker`

**Edit3**: It seems that the problem doesn't occur any more. Maybe some system updates fixed it?

Comment: This may be answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100010/no-password-asked-at-login-screen-just-start-session-button-with-lightdm/102222#102222)

Comment: @xtrchessreal thank you but apparently I do not belong to the group `nopasswdlogin`.

Answer (score 1):

Open *System parameter*

[image]

Go to *Security and confidentiality* -> *Password option*

[image]

And you just have to switch off the button **Automatic password** (don't forget to unlock the option with the button on the top)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately I do not have the button "Automatic password" on this window (everything else is present).