# Can someone log in as root without a password?

Tags: 20.04

I have one doubt, in ubuntu 20.04 direct login is possible without password. It means one user startup system with root without entering the root password directly wake-up with root, anybody please tell me how to do

Comment: With `root`? ... Possible, Yes ... Advised, No ... See: [Desktop automatic login as root on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1422123) ... If you change your mind, as you should, to use a normal user instead, then see: [How do I set up password-less login via GUI in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1462841)

Comment: Anyone with physical access to a machine can enter as root. This is computing 101.

Answer (score 4):

> in ubuntu 20.04 direct login is possible without password.

Yes.

> It means one user startup system with root without entering the root password directly

No. With some remarks: having your actual hands on a system anyone can boot into grub or start a live session, mount the disks and alter anything. The 2nd you can prevent by locking your BIOS but that is a hassle.

> wake-up with root,

No. We do not use root as a user. We use "sudo", that elevates permissions for a limited time (the default is 15 minutes).

The method using "sudo" is ease of use combined with good security. But the user itself is ofcourse ultimately the weakest part of the chain.